# Where did this -11 came from?

Tags: javascript

I was playing around with the following code:

```
function recaller(){
    while(x-- > 0)recaller();
}

var x = 10;
recaller();
alert(x); //-11?
```

But I was astonished to find that the `x` now holds the value of `-11`

I later added `alert(x);` above the `while`, to see if it displayed correctly the numbers `10` to `0` and it did.

Can someone explain me where did the `-11` came from?, my debugging skills failed me this time and I have no clue how to keep testing

Comment: Where is the `alert` that gave you `-11`?

Comment: you can better use `console.log` instead of `alert`

Comment: @gdoron updated question, after `var x = 10;recaller();`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are recursing into `recaller`, so `x` gets decremented lots of times at the end of the recursion — for each time you recurse, when you exit that recursive call the `while` loop condition will be checked again, and that expression decrements `x`. Consider what happens if we start with `x = 2`:

1. `x` is 2, we call `recaller` (first time) enter its while loop which checks `x` is greater than zero, decrements  and…
2. `x` is 1, we call `recaller` (second time) enter its while loop which checks `x` is greater than zero, decrements and…
3. `x` is 0, we call `recaller` (third time) enter its while loop which checks `x` is greater than zero *which it isn't*, decrements (`-1`) and returns
4. unwind the stack once to the second time; in its while loop, check `x` is greater than zero (no), decrements (`-2`) and returns
5. unwind the stack once to the first time; in its while loop, check `x` is greater than zero (no), decrements (`-3`) and returns
6. return to top level flow
7. `x=-3`

Comment: That's not it. The `if` is the reason you get the right output in my fiddle. Take a look on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqhcj/1/). Now you get `-9`.

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
var x = 10;
alert(x--); // Displays 10
alert(x); // Displays 9
```

x-- is a post-decrement operator, i.e. executes after the main eval. Thus:

```
if(x-- > 10) { 
  // Executes when x is > 10 before decrementing
}
```

You are doing a recursive looping. I.e. you do:

```
function recaller(){
    while(x-- > 0)recaller();
}
```

Which:

- Compares x to 10
- Calls recursively
- Decrements x

Since your codition is `x > 0`, it will exit from the innermost call to `recaller` when x = 0, then decrement once, exit into the next recursive call, etc., until you reach -11.

Answer (score 2):

As you probably know, `x--` decrements `x` and then returns its value before the decrement. We can also write your code like this:

```
function recaller() {
    while(true) {
        var oldX = x;
        x--;
        if(!(oldX < 0)) {
            break;
        }
        recaller();
    }
}
```

Now it is easier to put logging in there. I think it's a little easier to see with some indentation, so I have a few functions not shown here. With some logging, it looks like this:

```
function recaller() {
    indent();
    log("Recaller called");
    while(true) {
        log("In loop, before decrement and test");
        var oldX = x;
        x--;
        log("In loop; decremented");
        if(!(oldX > 0)) {
            log("Test failed");
            break;
        }
        log("Test succeeded");
        log("In loop, before recursion");                    
        recaller();
        log("In loop, after recursion");
    }
    log("About to return from recaller");
    dedent();
}
```

You can [see the result](http://jsfiddle.net/qRpbE/) on JSFiddle.

Looking at the log, you can tell that it's decrementing it (to down below zero) even when the test fails, resulting in the negative number.

Comment: +1 I wish I could debug like that, it would have saved a lot of hours of my life.